# Should I grind the early missions in order to Fulton Recover more comrades?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-hd-collection, metal-gear-solid-peace-walker

You can replay missions in Metal Gear Solid: Peace Walker, and each time you play, any soldiers you capture with Fulton Recovery make their way to Mother Base, where you can put them to work.  More members of the MSF means more money and research for me, but most of the soldiers that I'm capturing in the very early game have D and E ranked stats.

**Is it worth grinding the early missions to build up the Mother Base population early, or should I hold out for higher-ranked captures later in the game?**

Comment: This is largely opinion based. You can get more workers now and replace them later, or hold out until later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a stealth and non-lethal player, I was capturing soldier non-stop.

And I reccomend you to do the same, more soldier, even low-level as the first I had, will accumulate enought to unlock R&D faster. And you can ditch out low-level soldier when you have higher-level incoming.

Also, Fulton are produced fast enought to allow you to use them all in each mission, so 10 soldier by 10 soldier, you still have the time for accumulating the 300 soldier for each room of Outer Heaven.